# What is the proper procedure for evaluation of facial recognition models for research papers?

Tags: python, face-recognition

Recently I had to reproduce accuracy of one facial recognition model to see is the accuracy the same as in the paper. For testing I had one '.txt' file from which I obtained dictionary with keys 'matches' and 'not_matches' and whose values are lists of tuples. So, I implemented the following code:

```
def get_accuracy_parameters(json_distances_path, threshold):
with open(json_distances_path, 'r') as f:
    distances = json.load(f)
match_list = distances['matches']
not_match_list = distances['not_matches']
TP, FP, TN, FN = 0,0,0,0
for distance_val in match_list:
    if distance_val <= threshold:
        TP += 1
    else:
        FN += 1
for distance_val in not_match_list:
    if distance_val <= threshold:
        FP += 1
    else:
        TN += 1
TPR = TP/(TP + FN)
FPR = FP/(FP + TN)
Acc = (TP + TN)/(TP + FN + FP + TN)
FAR = FPR # false acceptance rate
FRR = FN/(TP + FN) # false rejection rate
return TPR, FPR, Acc, FAR, FRR
```

As you can see, one parameter of the function contains json path where I saved calculations of distances for tuples of images.  Is this the proper way to calculate accuracy? In some paper it is mentioned accuracy relative to FAR. How to calculate that? If this is not the appropriate way to calculate those parameters, please tell me what is the correct way to do it.  I don't understand how to obtain results of the form: Acc is 92.77 +-1.03% for FAR=0.1%, 86.27+-1.39% for FAR=0.01%. How can I reproduce those results? Is there some general procedure for calculation? Personally with that script I got Acc to be 59.something% instead of 99.something. I don't know where I am wrong.

Comment: Should the 'else' case in the matched list not be False Positive?

Comment: @MYousefi  I think it should be FN because we predicted that they don't match, which is false. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't the 'matches' data the pairs that the network has predicted as a match? If they are and the distance for a pair is outside of match tolerance wouldn't that be a False Positive?